# Instability due to different lumping dimensions in second-order linear system

Tags: stability, linear-system

I have a problem that consists of a linear hyperbolic differential equation with some boundary and initial conditions which leads after discretization in space using finite elements to the following second-order system:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol M \ddot {\boldsymbol d} + \boldsymbol C \dot {\boldsymbol d} + \boldsymbol {Kd} = \boldsymbol F \qquad (1)
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol M = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol M_{11} & \boldsymbol 0 \\ \boldsymbol 0 & \boldsymbol 0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad
\boldsymbol C = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol C_{11} & \boldsymbol 0 \\ \boldsymbol 0 & \boldsymbol C_{22} \end{bmatrix} \qquad
\boldsymbol K = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol K_{11} & \boldsymbol K_{12} \\ \boldsymbol K_{12}^\top & \boldsymbol K_{22} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

All of the $\boldsymbol M_{ii}$, $\boldsymbol C_{ii}$ and $\boldsymbol K_{ij}$ are symmetric;
$\boldsymbol M_{11}$ is positive definite and has a mass-matrix-like structure $\int_{\Omega^e} N_aN_b d\Omega$ on the element level;
$\boldsymbol C_{11}$ is positive semi-definite and $\boldsymbol C_{22}$ is positive definite, and they both have a mass-matrix-like structure $\int_{\Gamma^e} N_aN_b d\Gamma$ on the element level; I'm not sure about the positive-definiteness of $\boldsymbol K$.

I wish to solve this system using the Newmark explicit method, where the solution stage is
\begin{equation}
(\boldsymbol M+\gamma\Delta t \boldsymbol C + \beta \Delta t^2\boldsymbol K)\boldsymbol a_{n+1} = \boldsymbol F_{n+1} - \boldsymbol C \tilde {\boldsymbol v}_{n+1} - \boldsymbol K \tilde {\boldsymbol u}_{n+1} \qquad (2)
\end{equation}
where $\beta=0$, $\gamma=0.5$, and the tildes indicate predicted values. The corresponding *implicit* scheme is stable (all the eigenvalues of the polynomial eigenvalue problem corresponding to (1) are in the left half plane). Still, the *explicit* scheme, with lumped $\boldsymbol M$ and $\boldsymbol C$, is not. Note that while $\boldsymbol M$ is singular, the term $\boldsymbol M+\gamma\Delta t \boldsymbol C$ is not, and allows lumping and inversion of the left-hand side of (2).

The finite element discretization is carried out by linear elements, row-sum lumping is applied here for both $\boldsymbol M$ and $\boldsymbol C$.
However, while the lumping of $\boldsymbol M$ is carried out inside the element $\Omega^e$, the lumping of $\boldsymbol C$ is on the element boundary $\Gamma^e$, so the lumped element matrices for $\boldsymbol M$ and $\boldsymbol C$ are different, as the latter does not involve the element dimension perpendicular to $\Gamma^e$. I suppose that this is what caused the instability.

Has anyone encountered instabilities caused by a dimensional mismatch in lumping?
What can be done to remedy the situation?

Comment: You might want to explain how you actually lump the matrices. I'm also unclear about what "dimensional mismatch" actually is.

Comment: Thank you. Edited.